# $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, closed, surjective and, for every $y\in Y$, $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact in X. Prove that $X$ being T2 implies $Y$ is T2.

Tags: general-topology

I am preparing for an exam and I'm answering as many exercises I can. I got stuck on this one:

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a continuous, closed, surjective mapping such that for every $y\in Y$, $f^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact in X. Prove that if $X$ is T2, then $Y$ is T2.

Here's my work so far:

Let $y_1$ and $y_2$ be two different points in $Y$ and consider the inverse images of these two points. We know that $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{y_2\})$ are:

1. non empty because $f$ is surjective,
2. disjoint because no point can have two different images, and
3. compact (by hypothesis).

Now, because $X$ is T2, then we can separate the compact sets $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{y_2\})$ with two sets $U$ and $V$, that is, there are open sets $U$ and $V$ of $X$ such that
$f^{-1}(\{y_1\})\subset U$, $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})\subset V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

I tried considering the sets $W:=Y-(f(X-U))$ and $Z:=Y-(f(X-V))$. These are open sets in Y that contain $y_1$ and $y_2$, respectively.

EDIT:

I tried proving $W$ and $Z$ are disjoint. Here's my (failed) attempt:
Suppose (by contradiction) that there exists $b \in W\cap Z$. Then $b\in Z$ but $b \notin f(X-U)\cup f(X_V)$. Because $f$ is surjective, then there exists $a\in X$ such that $f(a)=b$. It must then happen that $a\in X-(U\cup V)$...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that $W$ and $Z$ **are** disjoint as $f^{-1}[W] \subseteq U$ and $f^{-1}[Z] \subseteq V$.

Just follow the definitions of the sets and show inclusions directly. No fancy tricks or set algebra required.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me. I edited my question and added a little attempt I had on my notebook but I thought was wrong. I still don't see my way through.

Comment: @416333 have you tried showing the two inclusions ( only one suffices the other omis similar)

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it. Should I edit my question or should I add a new answer?

Comment: @416333 you can upvote and accept if you have the solution and the answer helped you.

Comment: Great! I'll just remove the part where I say they aren't disjoint because I believe it can confuse readers. Thank you again.